# Multiple records update validation with the entire data set

Tags: oracle, api, asp.net-core, validation, .net-core

Currently, I have an endpoint that allows the update of multiple records. Before saving the changes to the database I need to validate the data that is being sent from the front end.

I am having an issue with some kinds of validations that require checks against all the other records in the database table. (Ex: ate intervals overlaps/gaps, unique pairs checks).

In these cases when I try to do the validations I have two sets of data

1. The data sent from the front end that are stored in memory/variable.
2. The data on the database.

For the validations to be run correctly I need a way to merge the data in memory(the updated records) with the data in a database(original records + other data that is not currently being updated).

Is there a good way of doing this that does not require loading everything on the memory and merging both datasets there?

Another idea I am thinking of is to open a database transaction set the new data to the database and then when executing the gaps/overlap check queries use dirty read. I don't know if this is a good approach though.

**Extra notes:** 
I am using Oracle as a database and Dapper to communicate with it.
The tables that need validation usually hold millions of records.
The same issue is for the create endpoint.

Another example 
I am trying to create entities. The create endpoint is called and it has these data on the body (date format dd/mm/yyy):

| StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 05/01/2022 |
| 10/01/2022 | 11/01/2022 |
| 12/01/2022 | 15/01/2022 |

In database I have these records saved:

| Id | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 06/01/2022 | 09/01/2022 |
| 2 | 16/01/2022 | 20/01/2022 |

I need to check if there are any gaps between the dates. If there are I need to send a warning to the user(data in the database can be invalid - the application has old data and I can't do anything about that at the moment).

The way I check for this right now is like by using the SQL below

```
WITH CTE_INNERDATA AS(
    SELECT s.STARTDATE, s.ENDDATE  
    FROM mytable s
    WHERE FK = somefkvalue
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT :StartDt AS STARTDATE, :EndDt AS ENDDATE FROM DUAL -- this row contains the data from one of the rows that came form the front-end
),
CTE_DATA AS (
    SELECT ctid.STARTDATE, ctid.ENDDATE, LAG(ctid.ENDDATE, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ctid.STARTDATE) AS PREV_ENDDATE FROM CTE_INNERDATA ctid
)
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM cte_data ctd
WHERE PREV_ENDDATE IS NOT NULL
AND PREV_ENDDATE < STARTDATE
```

Using this SQL query when validating the third row (12/01/2022 - 15/01/2022) there will be a gap between dates 09/01/2022 and 12/01/2022.
This issue would be fixed if instead of using union with a single row, to use it with all the rows send from the front-end but I can't figure out a way to do something like that.

**#Update**

I iterate through the records the frontend sent and call this method to check for gaps.

```cs
private async Task ValidateIntervalGaps(int someFkValue, DateTime startdate, DateTime endDate)
{
     var connection = _connectionProvider.GetOpenedConnection();

     var gapsCount = await connection.QueryFirstAsync<int>(@"<<Query from above>>",
     new { StartDt = startdate, EndDt = endDate, somefkvalue= someFkValue });

     if (gapsCount > 0)
     {
          // Add warning message here
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share what are you up to now, so that your problem can be reproduced easily?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I updated the post with an example.

Comment: How you are calling this `SQL code`  from your backend? I mean in `asp.net core`  how id you implement above code?

Comment: I iterate through the records the frontend sent and call this method to check for gaps.</br>
`private async Task ValidateIntervalGaps(int someFkValue, DateTime startdate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            var connection = _connectionProvider.GetOpenedConnection();

            var gapsCount = await connection.QueryFirstAsync<int>(@"<<Query from above>>",
                new { StartDt = startdate, EndDt = endDate, somefkvalue= someFkValue });

            if (gapsCount > 0)
            {
                // Add warning message here
            }
        }`

Comment: For getting gap from two date the easiest step we can do is , pass your date range like  this `var findGap= (endDate! - startDate!).TotalDays;`  it will show you the gap, now if the gap `>` greater than 0 then there is gap. I think this is the easiest thik. additionally you can use `store-procedure` rather passting the query. Another think you can use [`TimePeriodLibrary.NET`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimePeriodLibrary.NET/) to handle it. Hope that would help you.